# Can't find template by id when it's in imported file

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I'm creating simple custom element and i would like to import it from separated file. When it's in the same file `t` is giving right html element, but when it's in outside file it's `undefined`. Here is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="import" href="example-container.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <example-container></example-container>
  </body>
</html>
```

And `example-container.html`:

```
<template id="example-container">
    <style>
    </style>
</template>
<script>  
    // Make sure you extend an existing HTMLElement prototype
    var ExampleContainerProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    //var t = document.querySelector('#example-container');

    // Setup optional lifecycle callbacks
    ExampleContainerProto.createdCallback = function() {
        var t = document.querySelector('#example-container');
        console.log(t);
    };
    var ExampleContainer = document.registerElement('example-container', {prototype: ExampleContainerProto});
</script>
```

My another approach was to define `t` in the global scope, like this:

```
var t = document.querySelector('#wizard-container');
WizardContainerProto.createdCallback = function() {
    console.log(t);
...
```

And it work's fine, but i don't want to leave garbage in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

When using imports, the global `document` object refers to the parent page (index.html), not the imported page (example-container.html). You can get the imported document using `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`. So, it looks like you're querying the wrong document.

See [HTML Imports - #include for the web](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) on HTML5Rocks.

Comment: I've changed line `var t = ...` to `var t = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#wizard-container');` and now i've got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null`

Comment: @Scimonster As @PiotrŁużecki says, this doesn't seem to work: `document === document.currentScript.ownerDocument`